# Picking random link with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, parsing, dom, random

I am trying to make a script which it picks a random link and getting some info from its page. But while trying this:

```
$html= file_get_html('xxxbh.com/3/overview.aspx';); 
$title = $html->find('.userlist a', 0)->plaintext;
```

i found out that it keeps getting the first one. The html of the page is like this:

```
<td style="width: 20%; padding-bottom: 5px;"><a href="/item/18243/details.aspx">item.135</a></td>
<td style="width: 20px;"><im g style="padding: 0pt; float: none; vertical-align: middle;" src="/images/item_X.png"></td>
<td style="width: 20%; padding-bottom: 5px;"><a href="/item/11272/details.aspx">item.18</a></td>
<td style="width: 20px;"><im g style="padding: 0pt; float: none; vertical-align: middle;" src="/images/item_X.png"></td>
```

Can someone tell me a way please? Thanks in advance

Comment: What class are you using here ($html->find())?

Comment: $html->find('.userlist a', 0)->plaintext;
I dont know why but i can grab them with "userlist a"

Comment: No, i mean, what class is $html? What kind of object? You can't just do find() against a variable string.

Comment: ohhhh.. sorry didnt get it. i did $html= file_get_html('http://www.xxxbh.com/3/overview.aspx');

Comment: let me know if you need any more info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is more optimal solution, but if you don't have a lot of links you can grab all of them as an array and choose one randomly:

```
<?php
$links = $html->find('.userlist a');
$c = count($links);
$randomLink = $links[mt_rand(0, $c - 1)];
```

Comment: i get: Call to a member function children() on a non-object

Comment: @oMikR0n What about `$links[mt_rand(0, $c - 1)]` ?